# Import Zbrush model to Blender and retain polypaint, materials?

Tags: import, external-applications

How do you prepare a zbrush model with polypaint and materials so it can be opened in Blender and retain the polypaint and materials. Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'll need to bake your polypaint in Zbrush, so you can import the diffuse into Blender. If your model is too high poly you might want to create a low poly version so you can bake the polypaint of the high poly to the uv of the low poly.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, will give it a try.